# What is the meaning of $\delta (G)$ in graph theory?

Tags: graph-theory, notation

If $G$ is a graph, then what does $\delta(G)$ mean?

Comment: See here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EdgeConnectivity.html and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Graph_Theory/Definitions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the minimum degree of $G$. In other words, if $G = (V,E)$, then
$$
\delta(G) = \min_{v \in V} \deg(v)
$$